# Haskell data type definition depended on GADTs and function output

Tags: haskell, gadt

I would like to have a tensor data structure

```
data Nat where
    Zero :: Nat
    Succ :: Nat -> Nat

-- | A list of type a and of length n
data ListN a (dim :: Nat) where
    Nil  :: ListN a Zero
    Cons :: a -> ListN a n -> ListN a (Succ n)    

data Tensor a where
        Dense :: ListN a n -> ListN Int Nat -> Tensor a
```

A tensor is represented by a list of elements and a list of integers representing the dimensions of the tensor. For example [3,4,5,6] in ListN would mean you have 4 dimension were each dimension is 3, 4, 5 and 6 elements long respectively.
But now I want n of the first ListN be depended of the product of all integers stored in the second ListN because that's the amount of elements I can have in the first ListN.
But how should I do that?

Comment: Haskell already has a `Nat` type for this, and has multiplication type families to allow making such constraints. For example: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/GHC-TypeLits.html#t:-42-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you'll need a type-level dimension vector for your `Tensor` type, not just a `ListN Int Nat` value, so it's probably better to define `Tensor` with a `dims` type parameter.  You may also find it more convenient to have the dimensions first and the element type second, so something like:

```
data ListN (dim :: Nat) a where
    Nil  :: ListN Zero a
    Cons :: a -> ListN n a -> ListN (Succ n) a
infixr 5 `Cons`

data Tensor (dims :: [Nat]) a where
  Dense :: (Product dims ~ n) => ListN n a -> Tensor dims a
```

The missing piece here is `Product` which is a type-level function to multiply the dimensions.  It's a little tedious to multiple Peano naturals, but the following works:

```
type family Plus m n where
  Plus (Succ m) n = Plus m (Succ n)
  Plus Zero n = n

type family Times m n where
  Times (Succ m) n = Plus n (Times m n)
  Times Zero n = Zero

type family Product (dims) where
  Product '[] = Succ Zero
  Product (m : ns) = Times m (Product ns)
```

After that, the following type checks.  Note that I've made `Cons` an `infixr` operator up above to avoid a lot of parentheses:

```
t1 :: Tensor '[Succ Zero, Succ (Succ Zero), Succ (Succ (Succ Zero))] Int
t1 = Dense (1 `Cons` 2 `Cons` 3 `Cons` 4 `Cons` 5 `Cons` 6 `Cons` Nil)
```

If the number of elements is wrong, the constraint fails, so the following does not type check:

```
t2 :: Tensor '[Succ Zero, Succ (Succ Zero), Succ (Succ (Succ Zero))] Int
t2 = Dense (1 `Cons` 2 `Cons` 3 `Cons` 4 `Cons` 5 `Cons` Nil)
```

The full example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

data Nat where
    Zero :: Nat
    Succ :: Nat -> Nat

data ListN (dim :: Nat) a where
    Nil  :: ListN Zero a
    Cons :: a -> ListN n a -> ListN (Succ n) a
infixr 5 `Cons`

data Tensor (dims :: [Nat]) a where
  Dense :: (Product dims ~ n) => ListN n a -> Tensor dims a

type family Plus m n where
  Plus (Succ m) n = Plus m (Succ n)
  Plus Zero n = n

type family Times m n where
  Times (Succ m) n = Plus n (Times m n)
  Times Zero n = Zero

type family Product (dims) where
  Product '[] = Succ Zero
  Product (m : ns) = Times m (Product ns)

-- type checks
t1 :: Tensor '[Succ Zero, Succ (Succ Zero), Succ (Succ (Succ Zero))] Int
t1 = Dense (1 `Cons` 2 `Cons` 3 `Cons` 4 `Cons` 5 `Cons` 6 `Cons` Nil)

-- won't type check
t2 :: Tensor '[Succ Zero, Succ (Succ Zero), Succ (Succ (Succ Zero))] Int
t2 = Dense (1 `Cons` 2 `Cons` 3 `Cons` 4 `Cons` 5 `Cons` Nil)
```

As noted in the comments, there is a built in non-Peano `Nat` type that you *may* find easier to work with.  Rewritten to use that, the code would look like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE NoStarIsType #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

import GHC.TypeLits

data ListN (dim :: Nat) a where
    Nil  :: ListN 0 a
    Cons :: a -> ListN n a -> ListN (1 + n) a
infixr 5 `Cons`

data Tensor (dims :: [Nat]) a where
  Dense :: (Product dims ~ n) => ListN n a -> Tensor dims a

type family Product dims where
  Product '[] = 1
  Product (m : ns) = m * Product ns

-- type checks
t1 :: Tensor '[1,2,3] Int
t1 = Dense (1 `Cons` 2 `Cons` 3 `Cons` 4 `Cons` 5 `Cons` 6 `Cons` Nil)

-- won't type check
t2 :: Tensor '[1,2,3] Int
t2 = Dense (1 `Cons` 2 `Cons` 3 `Cons` 4 `Cons` 5 `Cons` Nil)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it seems it's want I need. I will try this out.

Comment: But how would a type signature look like for a function that only accepts a Tensor and a list where the product of the list is equal to the product of the list inside the Tensor.
I would think something like this but it doesn't type check:
(Product (lm :: [Nat]) ~ l) (Product (ns :: [Nat]) ~ n) (l == n )=> Tensor ns a  -> lm -> Tensor lm a

Comment: Are you imagining a function that would change a tensor's dimensions while keeping the same list of elements intact?  If so, you might want to ask this as a separate question, with some examples showing what you're trying to do.  Haskell doesn't support so-called "dependent types" directly, so it won't be as simple as writing a function like `reDim [1,2,3] my6ElementTensor`, but there are several tricks that can be used.

Comment: @k-a-buhr that is exactly what I wanted to do, but I have eventually created a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71676803/how-to-define-a-function-that-uses-a-list-which-product-of-numbers-is-the-same-a