# How to define a function that uses a list which product of numbers is the same as the amount of element in matrix in Haskell using GADTs?

Tags: haskell, gadt

I have a matrix representation of

```
data ListN (dim :: Nat) a where
    Nil  :: ListN Zero a
    Cons :: a -> ListN n a -> ListN (Succ n) a
infixr 5 `Cons`

data Tensor (dims :: [Nat]) a where
    Dense :: (Product dims ~ n) => ListN n a -> Tensor dims a
    Sparse :: Tensor n a
```

where `Product` makes sure `dims` is equal with `n` when you take the product of all the elements of `dims`.
Now I would like to have a creator function and a function that changes the dimensions of the tensor data type.

1. I would like to have one function that changes the dimensions of the matrix, but only if the product of a given `[Nat]` is equal to the `dims` of the matrix that has to be changed. I already thought of something like: `reshape :: (Product lm ~ l, Product (ns :: [Nat]) ~ n, l ~ n ) => Tensor ns a -> lm -> Tensor lm a`. But that doesn't type check.
2. I would also like to have a function that can create a Tensor when given a `[Nat]` but once again that list should have a product that is the same as the amount of elements of a given `ListN n a`. I thought of `fromList :: (Product lm ~ l, Product (ns :: [Nat]) ~ n, l ~ n ) => ListN n a  -> lm  -> Tensor lm a`. But that also doesn't type check.

Comment: "doesn't type check" is pretty vague. Error messages copied directly from the compiler output almost always help people answer questions.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing the error you're encountering is the most obvious problem with those types - `lm` doesn't have kind `Type`, as is required by the kind of `(->)`. This is easy to fix. Just remove it. It's a type that already appears in the signature in the place you actually need it. Type inference does all you need.

Filling in the standard stuff you left out:

```
{-# Language DataKinds, TypeFamilies, UndecidableInstances, StandaloneKindSignatures #-}

data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat

type Add :: Nat -> Nat -> Nat
type family Add m n where
    Add Zero n = n
    Add (Succ m) n = Succ (Add m n)

type Mult :: Nat -> Nat -> Nat
type family Mult m n where
    Mult Zero n = Zero
    Mult (Succ m) n = Add n (Mult m n)

type Product :: [Nat] -> Nat
type family Product xs where
    Product '[] = Succ Zero
    Product (x : xs) = Mult x (Product xs)

data ListN (dim :: Nat) a where
    Nil  :: ListN Zero a
    Cons :: a -> ListN n a -> ListN (Succ n) a
infixr 5 `Cons`

data Tensor (dims :: [Nat]) a where
    Dense :: (Product dims ~ n) => ListN n a -> Tensor dims a
    Sparse :: Tensor n a
```

Then these just work:

```
reshape :: (Product ns ~ Product lm) => Tensor ns a -> Tensor lm a
reshape (Dense l) = Dense l
reshape Sparse = Sparse

fromList :: (Product lm ~ n) => ListN n a -> Tensor lm a
fromList = Dense
```

Note that I simplified the constraints in each signature, too.

In `reshape` that was just to reduce redundancy. Matching on the `Dense` constructor brings the constraint into scope, which then is enough to allow it to synthesize the constraint it needs to package up in the new `Dense` constructor.

For `fromList`, I just simplified it down to the type of `Dense`. It is, after all, exactly the same function. (I can still see why you'd want to export it with a name that hides the internals though, so I understand why it might exist.)